# ORA-00904 while converting UTC date to Oracle date

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote the following query in Oracle, and it is working fine in one schema but giving an ORA-00904 error for the `utc_to_oracle` converter function in another schema.

```
 SELECT MIN(to_char(utc_to_oracle(start_t),'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi:ss')),
        MAX(to_char(utc_to_oracle(end_t),'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi:ss')) 
 FROM   ts.udata
 WHERE  entity_type='wxyz'
```

Error:

```
ORA-00904: "UTC_TO_ORACLE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action: Error at Line: 2 Column: 13
```

Why is it working on one schema but not the other?

Comment: `utc_to_oracle` is not a built-in function; it must be a user-defined function that exists in the first schema but not in the second. Would you want to duplicate the function, or access one version from multiple schemas? (And I'd also suggest you probably want `to_char(min())` rather than `min(to_char())`, to get the earliest date rather than the lowest day number, and the same for max.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! corrected it

Answer (score 0):

ORA-00904 occurs when you reference an invalid object.

You need to provide grants for the user defined object UTC_TO_ORACLE to the target user to have this executed.

```
GRANT SELECT ON UTC_TO_ORACLE TO XXX;
```